# Turn off hyperlinks in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

Version 1.4 of Windows Terminal introduced a new "feature" where it will automatically detect and underline links and shows a hint with "Ctrl+Click to follow link" on mouse-over.

I find this feature extremely annoying, because it gets in the way while I'm trying to copy output from script commands etc.

Does anyone know how to turn this feature off? I've checked in the settings window, and in the json config, but can't find any mention of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a setting available for the [Preview version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/customize-settings/interaction#automatically-detect-urls-and-make-them-clickable-preview) v1.9

> Automatically detect URLs and make them clickable (Preview)
> When this is set to true, URLs will be detected by the terminal. This will cause URLs to underline on hover and be clickable by pressing Ctrl. This is an experimental feature and its continued existence is not guaranteed.

```
Property name: experimental.detectURLs

Necessity: Optional

Accepts: true, false

Default value: true
```

> Important
> This feature is only available in Windows Terminal Preview.

There's also a UI based setting, under `Interaction`

[image]

Comment: Strange that detectURLs is an experimental feature in 1.9, when it seems to be a standard feature of 1.7. I might just put up with it until the new version is released.